# Database usage opinions

Tags: database

I have built a website that rotates menu display screens, one at a time. To accomplish this, each screen is inserted into the database to keep track of it each time the user launches the screen campaign.

Depending on the quantity of users, and how often they launch their campaigns, the id field of the table will eventually get very high. Each time a campaign is launched, the old rows are deleted for that particular campaign and user and starts fresh. Of course, the id values continue to increase.

Is it common for the id to get into 5, 6, 7 digits or higher? And does it really matter?

If so, how about a way to reset it back to 1. Or do I need to?

Comment: To reset your `auto_increment` value: `ALTER TABLE yourtable AUTO_INCREMENT=0`

Comment: does not matter at all.

Comment: need to make sure your keys are getting recycled though. An orphaned campaign with an id of 2 would cause a wee problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what database you are using and you didn't say what data type the column is.  It is possible to pick a datatype that is too narrow, say, tinyint, which conks out at 255, (if you are using MS-SQL Server). That is a limit easy to hit. Smallint 32,700 could be hit after a long while if you create data fast.  int is so big I've never hit the limit in real world scenarios 2,147,483,647.  I suppose if you were doing accounting in a hyperinflationary economy or high precision engineering work.  Big int is so big, you'd run out of numbers in several life times: 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.  So by the time you are using bigint, you're probably just wasting disk space.

Hopefully your UI doesn't expose the primary keys of your table to users because if they want them changed, changing a primary key is a hassle because it will cascade to all related tables.  So keep it secret and don't look at it yourself either, the number of digits it has is cosmetic & what really matters is how much space the datatype takes up and for most numeric datatypes that is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I would never have thought of doing that.
Have campaigns table with some sort of display order.
Add a column to your user table with campaign_id and date first shown., You could use login time for that. Then a bit of logic for when to rotate and what to.